# change background-image opacity responsive on page-width

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I program a theme for redmine with a logo in the header based on the responsive Red-Andy theme [here](https://github.com/rubo77/freifunk-red-andy) for [this site](http://issues.freifunk.in-kiel.de/).

I added a logo to the head, but if the site gets too narrow in width, the title moves over the logo.

How can I make this logo **half transparent** and in **grey-scale** once the site ungermines a certain width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css media queries and to an opacity of 0.5 and change the logo image with another in grayscale.

Let's say you have logo.png (default logo) and logo-gray.png (logo in gray scale) in this mark up:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="path/to/logo.png" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    div.logo > img {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var img = $('div.logo > img');
    if (width < 768) {
        img.attr('src', 'path/to/logo-gray.png');
    } else {
        img.attr('src', 'path/to/logo.png');
    }
});
```

**EDIT (Only CSS)**

Just create another logo in grayscale and opacity of 0.5 and replace background

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
       background-image: url('path/to/logo-gray-opacity.png');
    }
}
```

Comment: On [my site](http://issues.freifunk.in-kiel.de/) the logo is a background-image, so I could add something like `@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #header {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}` but this would change everything in the header.

Comment: Now I added `@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #header {
        padding-left:0;
        background: none;
    }
}` so there is no background-image on screens smaller than 768px

Comment: You could place a div that holds your logo in background image, inside your header, so set an opacity of 0.5 only to this div

Comment: That woud work, but I don't want to change the source code of redmine. The template has to be CSS only

Answer (score 0):

You will need media queries for this:

```
@media(max-width 250px) {
    .yourSelector{
  //css-code
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. Next time please provide actual code.